# Why i can't suggest edit

Tags: discussion

i am trying to suggest edit post but "edit" option link is disabled and it shows text

> Account is not allowed for suggested edit

How it will enable again?

**EDIT: screenshot added.**
[image]

Comment: Can you link to the post in question? And could you copy the _exact_ error message you're getting (the one you've put up there is just a guess I think)

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Check this out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits

Comment: i think i had too much suggested edits that have been rejected. so it is disabled...

Comment: monymirza, sorry about that, probably (partly) my fault. I accepted a large number of tag edits you made, but I disagreed on a few of them and rejected. I believe I took the time to pick/write a reason in every instance, so I hope that explains my reasoning.

Comment: IMHO, it hazardous to suggest edits for the tag wiki.  It is pretty arbritary what is accepted, and if someone with the privilege to reject edits disagrees with you just you a few times you're locked out of editing for 7 days.  BTDT: http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/are-there-any-guidelines-regarding-tag-wiki-descriptions The solution is simple: *Never* suggest a tag wiki edit. (Fixing non-trival typos in questions is usually not rejected - so that type of editing is "safe".)  But if you like to be able to suggest edits, leave the tag wiki to those with 2000 points or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't have the privilege of editing every post, the edit link could be disabled for the following reasons:

- There is already a pending suggested edit
- The queue for the pending suggested edits is full
- You had too much suggested edits that have been rejected

In the first case, you would just see the "edit" link disabled for specific posts, not for every posts.

Since I don't see pending suggested edits, or they are not too much, I would guess it is because rejected edits. If that is true, then you are not allowed to suggest further edits for the next 7 days.

As side note, I would suggest not to start suggesting too much consecutive edits. Not being allowed to suggest further edits happened to me too on another Stack Exchange site, and that because I started adding a tag I thought relevant for some questions, when other users thought it was not relevant.
Since suggested edits are not disabled when just four suggestions are rejected, it is better to make few suggested edits per time, and wait those edits are approved/rejected. At least, you can learn from the suggested edits that are rejected, and see if your edits are correct, or well accepted from the community. If you make the same kind of edit (as it happened to me with the questions to which I added the same tag), and that is considered wrong, then you are probably going to be blocked.

Keep in mind that avoiding a user can suggest further edits when consecutive suggested edits are rejected is an automatic action taken from Stack Exchange code; it's not an action taken by one or more users.